# How to get recursion coefficients for a Chebychev filter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I've been using [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/dsp-book/dsp_book_Ch20.pdf) to help me understand recursive filters, and I'm to the point where I'd like to design a lowpass Chebychev filter. The book provides kind of a cookbook for the recursion coefficients. For example, a 2-pole filter with 0.5% ripple and fc=0.25 would have coefficients:

```
a0= 2.858110E-01 a1= 5.716221E-01 a2= 2.858110E-01 
                 b1= 5.423258E-02 b2= -1.974768E-01
```

where each successive filtered value is calculated by:

```
y[n] = a0 * x[n] + a1 * x[n-1] + a2 * x[n-2] + ... 
                   b1 * y[n-1] + b2 * y[n-2].
```

From what I can gather from https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheby1.html the code to calculate coefficients for the same filter in Matlab would be:

[b,a] = cheby1(2, 0.1737, 0.5)

where 0.1737 is the 0.5% ripple converted to decibels (40*log10((1+0.05)/(1-0.05))) and the 0.5 is the cutoff frequency on a scale of 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 0.5 like in the book.
This produced 3 numbers each for a and b.

```
b =  0.4470    0.8939    0.4470


a =  1.0000    0.5508    0.2731
```

But these have no resemblance to the numbers from the book, and there shouldn't be 3 numbers for b. Matlab says these 6 numbers are "transfer function coefficients" while the book calls the 5 numbers "recursion coefficients." My question is: how do I calculate the 5 recursion coefficients in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in the coefficients arises because of the following:

1. The book and Matlab's [`cheby1`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheby1.html) function use **different defintions** for the **cuttof frequency and ripple**.

   In the book, the filter has DC gain 0 dB, the ripple is upwards (that is, the filter amplifies some frequencies), and the gain is −3 dB at the cutoff frequency.

   In Matlab, the filter has maximum gain 0 dB (which does not necessarily occur at DC), the ripple is downwards (so the filter does not amplify at any frequency), and the gain at the cutoff frequency in dB equals minus the specified ripple.
2. In the ripple, your **conversion from percentage to dB**, using `40*log10((1+0.05)/(1-0.05))`, is **not correct**: it should be either `20*log10(1+0.005)` or `-20*log10(1-0.005)` (or their average `10*log10((1+0.005)/(1-0.005))`, which is perhaps what you meant). The book seems to use the second option; the numerical difference between these definitions is small anyway.
3. The **coefficients** do have the same meaning in both cases, but the **order and signs** are different. Denoting Matlab's coefficient vectors by `b`, `a` as given by `cheby1`, and the book's coefficients by `a0`, `a1`, `a2`; `b1`, `b2`, the equivalence is: `b = [a0 a1 a2]`; `a = [1 -b1 -b2]`.

The equivalence in item 3 is easily established by comparing the recursive equation in your question with the expression for *H*(*z*) in [Matlab's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheby1.html#bucqk89-3).

To confirm 1 and 2, it is useful to plot the frequency response of the filter using [`freqz`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html). For the book's version,

```
a0=2.858110E-01; a1=5.716221E-01; a2=2.858110E-01;
b1=5.423258E-02, b2=-1.974768E-01;
freqz([a0 a1 a2],[1 -b1 -b2])
```

gives the magnitude response (the second image is a zoomed version of the first)

[image]

[image]

The ripple is −20*log10(1-0.005) = 0.044 dB upwards, and the gain is −3 dB at normalized frequency 0.5.

On the other hand, Matlab's design

```
[b,a] = cheby1(2, -20*log10(1-0.005), 0.5);
freqz(b,a)
```

gives (again, the second image is a zoomed version of the first)

[image]

[image]

The ripple is seen to equal the specified value but downwards, that is 20*log10(1−0.005) = −0.044 dB, and the gain at normalized frequency 0.5 equals that value.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed explanation. On the conversion of ripple percent to dB, I used the formula directly from Matlab's webpage. https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheby1.html

"Peak-to-peak passband ripple, specified as a positive scalar expressed in decibels.

If your specification, ℓ, is in linear units, you can convert it to decibels using Rp = 40 log10((1+ℓ)/(1–ℓ))."

I probably misundertsood what ℓ was.

Comment: @Adjwilley I hadn’t seen that formula. It’s probably a mistake by them. 10 instead of 40 makes more sense, and agrees with the curves obtained from the output coefficients